# RecyclerView should show half of previous and next item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scroll

I have a horizontal scrolling `RecyclerView`. I have 50 items. I go to 25th item immediately after creating the `RecyclerView` using `scrollToPosition` method. Now i want the 25th item to be in the centre of the screen. 24th and 26th items should be visible only half on either sides.
`RecyclerView` width is match parent. Parent is a `LinearLayout`. I am also using `LinearSnapHelper`.
The problem I face is, after scrolling to 25th item using `scrollToPosition`, 25th item is at the start of the screen. 24th item is not visible. Once i scroll the `RecyclerView` slightly, the snap starts working and 25th item comes to the centre and 24th and 26th items appear on either sides.
After this everything works fine. Only the inital position is not right. I want 25th item to be at the centre of the screen, not at the start of the screen. Thanks in advance. If anyone needs more information please mention in comments, I will update my question.

Answer (score 0):

Create Custom Linear Smooth Scroller

```
class SmoothCenterScroller(private val mContext: Context) : LinearSmoothScroller(mContext) {
override fun calculateDtToFit(
    viewStart: Int,
    viewEnd: Int,
    boxStart: Int,
    boxEnd: Int,
    snapPreference: Int
): Int {
    return (boxStart+(boxStart-boxEnd) /2) - (viewStart + (viewEnd - viewStart)-2)
}
}
```

Usage:

```
val smoothScroll =  SmoothCenterScroller(mRecyclerView.context)
    smoothScroll.targetPosition = TARGET_POSITION
    layoutManager.startSmoothScroll(smoothScroll)
```